# Java. Regular Expressions. How to mix NOT with AND?

Tags: java, regex

I have a string (VIN) like this:

```
String vin = "XTC53229R71133923";
```

I can use OR to see if there are characters Q,O,I:

```
String regExp = ".*[QOI].*";
```

This works.

However I can not check that any of these 3 letter are NOT in the string.

It means: (NOT Q) AND (NOT O) AND (NOT I).
I tried negative lookahead:

```
String regExp = "(?!.*[QOI].*)";
```

This doens't work. In "XTC5**Q**3229R71133923" it returns ***true***.

The **main** **issue** - I have 2 conditions:

1. Number of characters (A-Z0-9) in the string should be 17.
2. The string should not have Q,O,I.

I can check this with 2 regexps:

1. `String regExp = "^([A-Z0-9]{17})$"; //should be true`
2. `String regExp = ".*[QOI].*"; //should be false`

But is there a way to **combine** these 2 checks **in one regular expression**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about just using a custom range that doesn't include the characters you do not want?

```
String regexp = "^([A-HJ-NPR-Z0-9]{17})$";
```

Comment: However I really would like to get how to combine AND and NOT for some more diffucult issues if this is possible...

Comment: Custom ranges are almost always better even for more complex cases, as they're rather simple to understand, compared, say, to negative look-aheads. See this related question for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548787/regex-for-and-not-operation - yes, it seem possible, but, as per Zawinski's effect, you'll just end up with two problems instead of one , the other being your regular expression :)

Comment: Ok. It seems the best answer. It really converts my 2 RegExps in one. I'm curious still is there an elegant way to combine AND and NOT. However this really solves my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Please change "O" to "N" as I can't change only 1 character. In my question "O" should be excluded.

Comment: Good catch, my bad. Fixed

Answer (score 3):

Here you go `^[^QOI]{17}$`. Starting a charcter class with ^ means "do not match any of these characters".

Comment: This would also include the whole Unicode table as the allowed character set. I believe the question was how to exclude certain characters **while** keeping the `A-Z0-9` range

Comment: This might be not exact answer however it might be useful in some other cases.